# Bad Request for List registrants - /me/onlineMeetings/{id}/registration/registrants

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Trying to run the below query in the MS Graph explorer to view registrants and registrant info such as answers to custom questions:

[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/onlineMeetings/{id}/registration/registrants](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/onlineMeetings/%7Bid%7D/registration/registrants)

When I send the request though, I get a 400 Bad Request error with no further information.

I've tried multiple meeting IDs, both in the MS Graph Explorer and through HTTP calls in my own app, but no matter, what I keep getting the same error.

The meeting IDs I've tried have had a range of registrants that I've viewed inside MS Teams.

The MS account I am using has the correct consent permissions in MS Graph as well.